# What does it mean for two matrices to be orthogonal?

Tags: linear-algebra, orthogonality

Firstly, please bear in mind that I do not have much knowledge about linear algebra. Secondly, I am not asking about some mathematical definitions but rather a more physical definition of this mathematical meaning.

So, the problem is that I can understand the meaning of orthogonality between two vectors, they are just "lines" perpendicular to each other, but I can not physically perceive **what orthogonality means for matrices**.(like a $3\times 3$ one).
I mean if vectors are like lines in space, those being orthogonal is an easy concept to visualize. But how to visualize two orthogonal matrices?

I think that this is easier to explain to me if you first explain how does a matrix look like in space (visualization):

For example, for a $2 \times 2$, is it the area that its two contained vectors form in space? If it is that, then two orthogonal matrices are simply those two areas that are perpendicular to each other. If not, give me an analogous explanation.*

Comment: Orthogonality of two vectors _does not_ mean they are tangent to each other.

Comment: Sorry,i meant perpendicular.I will edit

Comment: @Mattos you understood the answers?, I have same doubt but not yet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will focus on $n\times n$ matrices since the $n\times m$ generalization is fairly straightforward. Define a matrix $$V=\begin{bmatrix}
     v_{11} & v_{12} & &... & & v_{1n}  \\
     v_{21} &   v_{22} &   &    &    & . \\
    .&    &  . &    &    &    .\\
     .  &    &   &.    &   &.\\
    v_{n1} &  . & .  &  .& .  &  v_{nn}
  \end{bmatrix}$$

For notational purposes, denote $v_{ab}=(\vec{v}_b)_a$, i.e. the $a$-th component of the vector $\vec{v}_b$. This way we can write $V$ as a matrix whose columns are vectors $\vec{v}_1,\vec{v}_2,..,\vec{v}_n$. Note that this changes nothing in the forthcoming conclusion. The matrix can then be written as:$$V=\begin{bmatrix}
     (\vec{v}_1)_1 & (\vec{v}_2)_1 & &... & & (\vec{v}_n)_1  \\
     (\vec{v}_1)_2 &  (\vec{v}_2)_2 &   &    &    & . \\
    .&    &  . &    &    &    .\\
    (\vec{v}_1)_n &  . & .  &  .& .  &  (\vec{v}_n)_n
  \end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}
     . & . & .& .& .&   .\\
     . & .  & .  &   . & .   & . \\
    \vec{v}_1&   \vec{v}_2 &  . &   . & .   &    \vec{v}_n\\
     .  &  .  & .  &.    &  . &.\\
      .&   . & .  & .   &.    & . 
  \end{bmatrix}$$
This way, computing $V^T V$ gives:
$$V^T V=\begin{bmatrix}
     . & . & \vec{v}_1^T& .& .&   .\\
     . & .  & \vec{v}_2^T  &   . & .   & . \\
    .&   . &  . &   . & .   &    .\\
     .  &  .  & .  &.    &  . &.\\
     . &  . & \vec{v}_n^T  &  .& .  &.  
  \end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
     . & . & .& .& .&   .\\
     . & .  & .  &   . & .   & . \\
    \vec{v}_1&   \vec{v}_2 &  . &   . & .   &    \vec{v}_n\\
     .  &  .  & .  &.    &  . &.\\
     . &  . & .  &  .& .  &.  
  \end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}
     |\vec{v}_1|^2 & \vec{v}_1\cdot\vec{v}_2 &  .& . &   \vec{v}_1\cdot\vec{v}_n\\
     \vec{v}_1\cdot\vec{v}_2  & |\vec{v}_2|^2  &   . & .   & . \\
    .&   . &  . &   .    &    .\\
     .  &  .  & .     &  . &.\\
     \vec{v}_1\cdot\vec{v}_n  & .  &  .& .  &|\vec{v}_n|^2 
  \end{bmatrix}$$
where we have defined $\vec{v}_i\cdot \vec{v}_j=\sum_a (\vec{v}_i)_a(\vec{v}_j)_a$ and used $\vec{v}_j\cdot\vec{v}_j=\vec{v}_j\cdot\vec{v}_i$.

Now, if $V$ is an orthogonal matrix, meaning $V^T V=\mathbb{1}_{n\times n}$, it means that $$\vec{v}_i\cdot \vec{v}_j=\delta_{ij}$$
where I have defined $\delta_{ij}=1$ when $i=j$ and $\delta_{ij}=0$ when $i\neq j$.

**Conclusion:** An $n\times n$ orthogonal matrix V is a matrix that consists of columns (or rows) which are orthonormal vectors, i.e. they are unit vectors that are normal to each other. These vectors can form a basis for an n-dimensional vector space since they are linearly independent*.
$$\boxed{V^TV=\mathbb{1}_{n\times n}\ \longleftrightarrow\ \vec{v}_i\cdot \vec{v}_j=\delta_{ij}}$$

Extra: the determinant of $V$ gives the oriented volume (in n-dimensions) of a hypercube whose sides are formed by the vectors which are either the rows or the columns (since $\det{V}=\det{V^T}$) of $V$.

*Linear independence can be seen from the fact that taking the det of both sides of $V^TV=\mathbb{1}_{n\times n}$ gives $(\det{V})^2=1$.

Answer (score 23):

There are two possibilities here:

1. There's the concept of an orthogonal matrix. Note that this is about a *single* matrix, not about *two* matrices. An orthogonal matrix is a real matrix that describes a transformation that leaves scalar products of vectors unchanged. The term "orthogonal matrix" probably comes from the fact that such a transformation preserves orthogonality of vectors (but note that this property does not completely define the orthogonal transformations; you additionally need that the length is not changed either; that is, an orthonormal basis is mapped to another orthonormal basis). Another reason for the name might be that the columns of an orthogonal matrix form an orthonormal basis of the vector space, and so do the rows; this fact is actually encoded in the defining relation $A^TA = AA^T = I$ where $A^T$ is the transpose of the matrix (exchange of rows and columns) and $I$ is the identity matrix.

   Usually if one speaks about orthogonal matrices, this is what is meant.
2. One can indeed consider matrices as vectors; an $n\times n$ matrix is then just a vector in an $n^2$-dimensional vector space. In such a vector space, one can then define a scalar product just as in any other vector space. It turns out that for real matrices, the standard scalar product can be expressed in the simple form
   $$\langle A,B\rangle = \operatorname{tr}(AB^T)$$
   and thus you can also define two matrices as orthogonal to each other when $\langle A,B\rangle = 0$, just as with any other vector space.

   To imagine this, you simply forget that the matrices are matrices, and just consider all matrix entries as components of a vector. The two vectors then are orthogonal in the usual sense.

Answer (score 7):

It is not common to say that two matrices are orthogonal to each other, but rather one speaks of a matrix being an orthogonal matrix.

Formally, a matrix $A$ is called orthogonal if $A^TA = AA^T = I$.
In other words, the columns of the matrix form a collection of orthogonal (and normed vectors); if you take two distinct columns they are orthogonal as vectors. 
(You could also consider rows.)

"Physically" an orthogonal matrix corresponds to a distance preserving linear transformation (such as a rotation) of the space.

Comment: Just to clarify something,if we have say a 2x2 matrix,this means that like a vector is a "line" in space,then the matrix is an area in space that is formed by the vectors that are inside the matrix?

Comment: @LandosAdam not quite. The two vectors in the matrix can be thought of as the axis of a (new) coordinate system. The transformation I mention take the "standard" coordinate vectors to these new coordinate vectors.

Comment: So,what exactly is a matrix if we are to visualize it in the same way as we visualize a vector in space?

Comment: An ordered list of vectors.

Comment: Yes,but this does not give me a visualization.I meant,like a vector is a line in space,what can we say about a matrix?What does it represent geometrically?Is it just there to transform or there is a graphical representation for it?

Comment: I do not see why this does not give a visulization. You have one vector you like to think of as one line. So now you have a list of two vectors, so you have two lines. Like two coordinate axis. This are two lines. Together, they span a plane. *But* the two coordinate axis are more specific then just the plane they span as two other lines could span the same plane.

Comment: So,if the two vectors of a 2x2 form a plane,then if we talk about two orthogonal matrices,we mean that the two planes that they create are perpendicular to each other?

Comment: No we do not mean this. And I do not talk about two matrices being orthogonal at all. You could say (roughly) a 2-by-2 matrix is orthogonal if "the two lines are orthogonal."

Comment: So,visually,it means that the matrix has a shape of square or rectangle?

Comment: Yes. If you think of the two vectors as the sides of a parellogram. Then the matrix being orthogonal would mean it is a square. (It is a square as one also imposes the vectors being normed.) To come back to my explanation. The matrix in fact describes a transformation that is a rotation or reflection of the square forme by the two standard vectors $(1,0)$ and $(0,1)$

Comment: Yes,i know can understand.One last clarification if you can.The vectors of the matrix that you are refering to are the lines or the columns of the matrix and why not the other?

Comment: This is pure convention; one can do either but one should stick to one convention.  Often one writes vectors as a column, then it is more natural to think of the columns as vectors (rather than the rows). Also, one may want to have $Av$ (product matrix by column vector) yield the image of $v$ under the maps associated to $A$.

Answer (score 5):

$\newcommand{\Reals}{\mathbf{R}}$Let $m$ and $n$ be positive integers. The set $\Reals^{m \times n}$ of all real $m \times n$ matrices is "essentially" the space $\Reals^{mn}$ of all real vectors with $mn$ components: Just put the entries of a matrix into a single column in some specified order. The ordinary dot product in $\Reals^{mn}$ allows us to speak of Euclidean geometry in the space of $m \times n$ matrices. In particular, we may speak of two matrices being "orthogonal" if their dot product is zero.

It turns out that the dot product of two $m \times n$ real matrices $A$ and $B$ has a simple formula, $\operatorname{tr}(A^{T}B)$. (In words, multiply the transpose of $A$ by $B$, then add up the diagonal entries of the resulting square matrix.)

However, as quid says, there's a completely different definition of "orthogonal" as a property of *a single $n \times n$ matrix*, which is "If $u$ and $v$ are vectors in $\Reals^{n}$, then $u \cdot v = 0$ if and only if $Au \cdot Av = 0$." This turns out to be equivalent to "Multiplication by $A$ preserves all concepts of Euclidean geometry", or "The columns of $A$ form an orthonormal basis of $\Reals^{n}$", among others.

If someone comes to you and says, "Let $A$ and $B$ be two orthogonal matrices, ...", quid's interpretation is probably what they mean. But if lives depend on it, clarify with the asker. :)

Comment: I understand all this.But this is a mathematical explanation which i already know.Don't get me wrong,it is a good answer but not the answer i am seeking.I just want to visualize what a matrix is like i visualize what a vector is,and then visualize what orthogonal matrices are.

Comment: One also should never forget to ask with respect to which inner product. ;-) Nice answer.

Comment: @LandosAdam: No offense taken if this answer isn't helpful to you. :) But it sounds as if the picture you're seeking boils down to, e.g., "A (non-zero) $2 \times 2$ real matrix is an arrow in four-dimensional space." That said, it may help your intuition to consider matrix groups, e.g., $SL(2, \mathbf{R})$ (a hyperboloid-like hypersurface in $\mathbf{R}^{4}$) or $SO(3)$ (a "twisted product" of an ordinary sphere and a circle in $\mathbf{R}^{9}$ that casts an obvious "shadow" in $\mathbf{R}^{6}$ if you look only at the first two columns).

Answer (score 2):

I think this is the crux of your question:

> first explain how does a matrix look like in space(visualization)

Matrices are harder to visualize than vectors.

Here's one way to attack the problem. In the context you care about, a matrix is really a way to move vectors around in the plane - it's a way to represent a linear transformation. (I won't say more now since you may know that. If you don't, I can elaborate.) The unit square with corners $(0,0), (1,0), (0,1), (1,1)$ always moves to a parallelogram formed by two vectors with their tails at the origin. That parallelogram is one way to visualize the matrix. Then the matrix is orthogonal when that parallelogram is a unit square - the two edge vectors from the origin are orthogonal (and also of length 1).