# Symmetric matrix - orthogonal to any diagonal matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I need to find a symmetric matrix of real values (not the zero matrix) of any order that is orthogonal to any diagonal matrix of real values.
Any hints?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put zeros on the diagonal and ones on the off-diagonal.

Comment: So this is only for the diagonal matrix of all zeros. I need it to be orthogonal to any diagonal matrix

Comment: I assume here that $A\perp B$ iff the trace of $AB$ is equal to $0$. This translates to the inner product of the corresponding "long vectors" of $A$ and $B$ to be orthogonal. This will be the case for the matrix I described. Thus you must be working with a different orthogonality?

Comment: You right. Got it

Comment: OK great - you can put whatever you want on the off-diagonals as long as you are symmetric (and you want at least two nonzero entries).

Answer (score 1):

*Hint:*  Using the definition of orthogonality of matrices to be $\text { tr}(AB^t)=0$ (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1262311)), all that matters is what happens on the diagonal of the product matrix $AB^t$.

Think zeros on the diagonal...  since $B$ is diagonal,  this will result in $AB^t$ having zeros on the diagonal...